# Python-Time Series how to get predicted values for specific weeks

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, arima, multivariate-testing, vector-auto-regression

I am trying to use multivariate time series for a data set. How do I predict next 10 weeks data points?

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model import VAR

df = pd.read_csv('SomeData.csv') # 10 years worth of weekly data
df.columns: weekly,col1,col2
dtypes: weekly is datetime64[ns], col1,col2 with numerical values
df = df.set_index('weekly')


# Make final predictions
model = VAR(endog=ds)
model_fit = model.fit()
yhat = model_fit.forecast(model_fit.y, steps=1)
print(yhat)
# I get this from above [[1.71417524  2.65237582 8.17163656]]
```

Looks I am only get single predicted data points. How do I project next weekly data for specific weeks in python? I have done training and validation, I haven't put that here. Is there a parameter that I could pass in Time Series in Python? Can't seem to find it? I haven't used 'statsmodels' packages before, I tried to look through documentation as well. Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: You have `steps=1`, which gives you forecasts for one period ahead, but it sounds like you want `steps=10`?

Comment: @cfulton. Looking at the documentation link below does this mean steps should be interpret as next predicted data point? steps = 10 would be 10th week, step = 12 would be 12th week?https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VARProcess.html

Comment: `steps=10` would give you all forecasts for 1, 2, ..., 10 steps ahead. You can see this from the documentation for the `forecast` function (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VARProcess.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VARProcess.forecast) which shows that the output is an array shapes `(steps x neqs)`.